# Faster displaying in video pipeline in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, video, camera

I wrote an application that, with some other functions, displays up to 3 video streams in a tkinter GUI.

The streams don't have defined resolutions, so they come with what ever resolutions they have.

With 1 cam, my display thread is 4 times faster then my capture thread. That's ok, I could sync them with events (I am open for better ideas).

But with 3 cams my display thread is 4 times slower then my capture thread and i would like to make it faster.

I don't want to spam the whole class code, so I grabbed only the image pipeline from it.

Perhaps someone knows faster methods to achieve this functionality.

Here is the rough code I am talking about:

```
Video Class
    #get source
    self.cap = source
    #set resolution
    self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, set_width)
    self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, set_height)
    #set buffersize
    self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 0)
    
    self.t_capture = threading.Thread(target=self.capture)
        self.t_capture.name = "capture thread_"+str(self.order)
        self.t_capture.start()

    self.t_display = threading.Thread(target=self.display)
        self.t_display.name = "display thread_"+str(self.order)
        self.t_display.start()

    def Thread Capture #capture thread
        #counter for throughput
        gv.global_capture_counter_1 += 1
        self.ret, self.frame = self.cap.read()

    def Thread Display #display thread
        #counter for throughput
        gv.global_display_counter_1 += 1
        self.rgb_frame = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        #resizing depending on displayed videoframes, screensize and windowsize
        self.frame_resized = self.ratio_resize(image = self.rgb_frame, height=aim_height )
        #black bar behind fps text for better reading
        cv2.rectangle(self.frame_resized,(x, y0-text_height),(x+text_width,y0),text_color_bg, -1)
        #fps text
        record_frame = cv2.putText(self.frame_resized,self.FPS_Text,(x, y0),font,font_scale,font_color,font_thickness,line_type)
        #mqtt text
        record_frame2 = cv2.putText(record_frame,line,(x, y0),font_b,gv.global_mqtt_font_scale,font_color_b,font_thickness_b,line_type_b)
        self.pre_frame=Image.fromarray(record_frame2)
        self.ready_frame=ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.pre_frame)
        videolabel_1.configure(image=self.ready_frame)
        videolabel_1.image=self.ready_frame
```

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre] required.

Comment: Hi, to understand to ask questions in Stackoverflow like i should: Where did i failed besides the minimal rep. example?

Comment: MRE primarily. people can't debug your issue for you (*not* the purpose of this site in any case! [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask]) if you don't provide something debuggable. if you read the MRE article thoroughly, you'll have found a link to another article that teaches you debugging.

Comment: I hoped for alternative methods for my Image Pipeline.  I don't wanted to improve the existing Code with the existing methods.